# Close dialog when ESC key is pressed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How can i close a vuetify's [dialog](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/dialogs) opened without an activator, when the user press the ESC key on the keyboard?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add `@keydown.esc="dialog = false"` to `v-dialog` component

```html
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" @keydown.esc="dialog = false"></v-dialog>

data: () => ({
  dialog: false
}),
```

Working example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BJOOOQ

---

Additionally, if using dialog as custom component then possibly we need to emit input event:

```html
<template>
  <v-dialog :value="value" @keydown.esc="$emit('input')">
    <!-- content -->
  </v-dialog>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, with keyup it doesn't work, but with keydown ... interesting, a possible bug? @Tom works.

Comment: @benno I believe it's not a bug, just `keydown` was supported implemented for this case.

Comment: can you explain a little bit further, what is the difference between keydown and keyup in this case? But aniway, it works!

Comment: @benno as far as I understand, there is no difference in events per se. It's just that vuetify devs added `keydown` listener for `v-dialog` and they **didn't** add `keyup` listener. That's all.

Comment: This only works, if you have selected anything inside the modal. If there is no selection, the event will be triggered on the body and it will not work. Hence the solution of @Dazzle is sadly the better.

Answer (score 15):

This is the only way I was able to get it to work

```
mounted() {
    // Close modal with 'esc' key
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            this.$emit('close');
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 8):

this code maybe can help you

```
mounted() {
        let self = this;
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
            // If  ESC key was pressed...
            if (event.keyCode === 27) {
                // try close your dialog
                self.advanced_search = false;
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: It's much simpler, check my answer

Comment: @Traxo i khow this way can be... but benno  wants to use keyup!

Comment: how did you come to that conclusion? It isnt stated anywhere afaics

Answer (score 1):

the same principle as adding keypress binding to any vue component should work - add the following code to the v-dialog component :

```
 @keydown.esc="dialog = false"
```

working example ( note the close button click event handler as well )

https://codepen.io/yordangeorgiev/pen/WBeMGq

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is a Key Modifier. You can use `v-on:keyup.esc` directive on your dialog to detect if the `escape` key is detected.

Read [this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers) for more information about Key Modifiers

Comment: @benno Did you find a working solution for this issue? I have the same problem...

Comment: @Tom not until now, but I will post here if I have one.

Comment: `keyup` doesn't work. But `keydown` is supported, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

While the solutions others have mentioned work, there still are conflicts with the bounce animation, making it not work after playing it by clicking outside the dialog, etc.

Setting the `no-click-animation` property also fixes the animation when closing as otherwise it plays both the close and bounce animation:

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" @keydown.esc="dialog=false" no-click-animation></v-dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

@keydown.esc not working with my project. As far as I see it's good for Vue2 projects.

Working script:

```
mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Escape') {
            this.$emit('close');
            // Or any other way you want to close your modal
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At version 3.4.9 of Feb 2024. If you have used the `persistent` attribute, according to this [GitHub Bug Report](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/18989) This is still an issue. Some earlier Vuetify versions may work, others don't. I believe it is a bug.

On key event, it is not only bound to `esc` to close dialog. You may want `ctrl+alt+O` or `shift+option+X` to perform a special custom action of your own.

The safe workaround to handle it is to use mount and unmount event handler registration, and bypass the `keyup.{keyname}` event.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { onUnmounted } from "vue";
  const keyFunc = (e: KeyboardEvent) => e.key === "Escape" && (dialog.value = false);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyFunc);
  onUnmounted(() => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyFunc));
</script>
```